# Convert some quickfix messages into tags rather than errors

Tags: quickfix, tags

Often times I get way too many diagnostics from my compiler (eg., things beginning `note:`  which just provide context for the actual error), and I do not want to descend into these when I type `:cn`.

Can the quickfix window contain tag-like references, to be visited with `^]`, and can some of the compiler's diagnostic output be converted to such references?  That way `:cn` doesn't have to descend down long lists of contextual output, but I do have the option of visiting those files easily if I need to.

For example:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:67,
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:653:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _InputIterator, class> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>]’
  653 |  vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
      |  ^~~~~~
```

It makes sense to me that the `filename:line` pair on the `In file included from`  line should be something I could visit with `^]`, and I would prefer the `filename:line:column` associated with the `note:`  line to be that way too, instead of being treated as the next error in the list.

Comment: The core issue, here, seems to be that your `:help 'errorformat'` doesn't match the output of your compiler. As-is, your question is lacking a) a reproducible example, b) the current value of `errorformat`, c) an indication of what compiler you use.

Comment: More gently, I also thing the correct `'errorformat'` would get you everything you want. To help you get there, it would be great if you [edit] to include the things romainl requested.

Comment: I don't understand.  I have already included sample output from a compiler.  `errorformat` already _does_ match the compiler output, but I want to change its behaviour to insert tag references into the quickfix window rather than syntax errors.

Comment: It seems that an alternative error format could do better :-). Could you provide: The compiler output, the `errorformat` (`:set errorformat?`)?

Comment: No. If the sample you have given is treated as several errors, then your `efm` is broken and must be fixed. There is only one valid error, there, and the rest is just context, where you should already be able to do `gf`, for example. Again: what compiler?, what `efm`? where is the reproducible example. If you want us to help you change your broken `efm`'s behavior, the least you can do is show it to us.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment…

Without sourcing any config or making any assumption about the language, compiler, etc. feeding your sample to Vim with `$ vim --clean -q errorfile +copen` should give something like this:

[image: copen]

where…

- there is only one valid error (both `:cn` and `:cN` throw `E553`),
- you can already do `<C-w>gF` or some similar command on the "In file included from" filename.

Which almost covers all your needs, with one caveat: `test.cc` disappeared.

Now, if *your* `errorformat` finds more than *one* error in the given compiler output, it should be reputed broken and you should consider fixing it. Once it is fixed, you can then fine-tune it to your requirements.

We *may* be able to help, but we need to *see* your `errorformat` for that.